# debian snmp server temp?

Tags: snmp, mrtg, debian-jessie

I'm trying to query remote Debian Jessie hosts' cpu temp using the output of lm-sensors on remote host (which works) to generate an snmpd query to eventually graph with mrtg. Is there a better way to do this using snmp MIBS that already do this for temp (and what MIB should I be looking for)? I got lm-sensors to output straight temp by doing:

`sensors -u | grep temp2_input | awk '{print $2}'`

`40.000`

Comment: I thought that Debian Net-snmpd is built with the lmsensor Mib support and should give you a temp with for instance `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.16` or `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost lmSensors`

Comment: not that I could find in Jessie with `apt-cache search snmp | grep net` or running `snmpwalk -v 1 -c whatever localhost | sensors`, all I get is the lm-sensors version and lm-sensor lib version.